# Wildfly standalone.xml - host open especific myapp.war/somepath

Tags: java, wildfly, virtualhost, wildfly-9, undertow

I have an app called ***myapp.war***, but there are 2 entry points inside that war, one in root another in the ***/app2*** folder.

Nowadays the user accesses ***mycompany.com/myapp*** and ***mycompany.com/myapp/app2***.

I would like the user to enter through the domain ***myapp1.com*** would like to forward to ***myapp.war***, when it goes through the domain ***myapp2.com*** would like to forward to the same myapp.war but in the second case I would like to redirect to the ***/app2*** folder

I know how to do this if I have two war apps, but I would not like to do so because I would have many complications in keeping the updates.

Setting up my ***standalone.xml***

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
...
<server name="default-server">
...
<host name="myapp1.com" default-web-module="myapp.war"/>
<host name="myapp2.com" default-web-module="myapp2.war/app2 (This does not exist, I know...)"/>
```